# Attaching volume to already existing folder deleted all the data in digital ocean

Tags: digital-ocean

I bought a 100 gb volume and accidentally attached it to my var folder.
Now all the previous data is deleted

command I ran `mount -o discard,defaults,noatime /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-0DO_Volume_volume-sgp1-01 /var`

How can I undo this last action in digital ocean

Answer (score 0):

Unmounting returns you all of the data

1. Get the volume’s mount point with df if you don’t already know it `sudo df --human-readable --print-type`
2. Unmount the volume with umount. `sudo umount --verbose /mnt/use_your_mount_point`

if it shows that "device is busy", kill the processes

1. get the process by `sudo lsof +f -- /mnt/use_your_mount_point`
2. kill the process found `ps -ef | grep 1725 <--> ps -ef | grep <pid> AND/OR kill -9 pid`